# Make arara close pdflatex upon error

Tags: texstudio, arara

I am using arara and TexStudio, and before I started using arara, Texstudio would shut down the pdflatex process on hitting Stop Compiling. I'm using arara with the following commands:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
```

Whenever there's an error, I have to shut down the pdflatex process manually from the Task-Manager, since Stop Compiling won't shut down the process anymore when I use arara.

(I'm not using the English version of TexStudio, so I'm not entirely sure that what I'm hitting is called Stop Compiling. It's a big red square that tells TexStudio to stop compiling.)

Comment: Would `% arara: pdflatex: {interaction: nonstopmode}` help? This will make pdflatex finish the run, no matter if there had been an error or not, so you don't need the `stop compile` button at all.

Comment: @samcarter This tells me that there is no interaction argument in the pdflatex directive; I haven't played around with arara enough to know whether that is straightforward to implement

Comment: Sounds strange, which version of arara are you using? Can you show the whole error message?

Comment: @samcarter Version 3.0, the error message is as follows: 
`Oh no, there are arguments used in the diretive 'pdflatex' which
are not defined in the 'pdflatex.yaml' rule located at
'C:\Program Files (x86)\arara\rules'. You can either remove them
from the 'pdflatex' directive or add them to the list of
arguments in the 'pdflatex.yaml' rule. Here they are:
[interaction]`

Comment: @samcarter I checked the yaml file and it had this bit in it: `- identifier: action
  flag: <arara> --interaction=@{parameters.action}` Once I changed `interaction` in your code to `action`, it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: `interaction` seems to have been renamed in version 4.0, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Odd, I installed it in March I believe, so I would have thought I had the newest version...

Comment: 3.0 is the version currently shipped with latex distributions, as far as I know, 4.0 is still a development version - so unless you need special features, you should be fine with 3.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to fix the behaviour of the `stop compile` button, I would avoid to having to use it in the first place.

If you call `arara` with:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {interaction: nonstopmode}
```

(arara version 4.0)

```
% arara: pdflatex: {action: nonstopmode}
```

(arara version 3.0)

this will tell pdflatex to finish its run, no matter if there had beed errors or not -  so you will not need to aboard `pdflatex` manually.

Answer (score 8):

You can pass arara the command line option `halt-on-error`:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ERROR

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see from the picture, I clicked the “compile” button and it became green again after arara stopped.

Here I used TeXworks, but it should be the same with TeXStudio.

Comment: Well that's the odd thing, apparently as far as TexStudio is concerned, clicking the red button does what it should do: The mouse curser becomes unbusy, the red button grays out and the green button becomes available again. But when I change the code and run it again, the error message will stay the same, I can't delete any auxiliary files because they're still open, and the TaskManager shows an instance of pdflatex running already (and hitting the green button will start a second one.)

Comment: @sgf Sorry, but TeXStudio refuses to launch on my machine.

Comment: But are you sure that there isn't an instance of pdflatex running and TeXworks just pretends it stopped the process?

Comment: @sgf Yes, just checked. What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1